# Matching tuples with don't-care variables in Erlang

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I am looking for a way to find tuples in a list in Erlang using a partial tuple, similarly to functors matching in Prolog.  For example, I would like to following code to return `true`:

```
member({pos, _, _}, [..., {pos, 1, 2}, ...])
```

This code does not work right away because of the following error:

```
variable '_' is unbound
```

Is there a brief way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple cases it's better to use already mentioned [lists:keymember/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keymember-3). But if you really need `member` function you can implement it yourself like this:

```
member(_, []) ->
    false;
member(Pred, [E | List]) ->
    case Pred(E) of
        true ->
            true;
        false ->
            member(Pred, List)
    end.
```

Example:

```
>>> member(fun ({pos, _, 2}) -> true; (_) -> false end, [..., {pos, 1, 2}, ...]).
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but it seems that a predicate function is the only way to pass a pattern as an argument.

Comment: `lists:any` actually does exactly the same as this `member` function :)

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables I believe predicate function can be avoided if `member` will be implemented as a macro

Answer (score 3):

Use [lists:keymember/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keymember-3) instead.

Comment: Would this also allow for pattern matching? As the question is not about getting an equality match.

Comment: @WardB `lists:keymember(pos, 1, List)` for example in the question

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a macro using a list comprehension:

```
-define(member(A,B), length([0 || A <- B])>0).

?member({pos, _, _}, [{width, 17, 42}, {pos, 1, 2}, totally_irrelevant]).
```

It is not very efficient (it runs through the whole list) but it is the closest I can think to the original syntax.

If you want to actually extract the elements that match you just remove 'length' and add a variable:

```
-define(filter(A,B), [_E || A =_E <- B]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using list comprehension:

`Matches = [ Match || {Prefix, _, _} = Match <- ZeList, Prefix == pos].`

Comment: That's nice, but can it be re-written so that the pattern will be given as a function argument (e.g., for writing a "my_member" function)?

Comment: You can write it even simpler `[Match || {pos, _, _}=Match <- ZeList]` but it's _filter_ not _member_ functionality.

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables [Elem || Elem <- List, my_member(Elem)] but you can do the same with lists:filter(fun my_member/1, List)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to do what match specs do and use the atom `'_'` instead of a raw `_`.  Then, you could write a function similar to the following:

```
member(X, List) when is_tuple(X), is_list(List) ->
    member2(X, List).

% non-exported helper functions:

member2(_, []) ->
    false;
member2(X, [H|T]) when not is_tuple(H); size(X) =/= size(H) ->
    member2(X, T);
member2(X, [H|T]) ->
    case is_match(tuple_to_list(X), tuple_to_list(H)) of
        true -> true;
        false -> member2(X, T)
    end.

is_match([], []) ->
    true;
is_match(['_'|T1], [_|T2]) ->
    is_match(T1, T2);
is_match([H|T1], [H|T2]) ->
    is_match(T1, T2);
is_match(_, _) ->
    false.
```

Then, your call would now be:

```
member({pos, '_', '_'}, [..., {pos, 1, 2}, ...])
```

This wouldn't let you match patterns like `{A, A, '_'}` (checking where the first two elements are identical), but if you don't need variables this should work.

You could also extend it to use variables using a similar syntax to match specs (`'$1'`, `'$2'`, etc) with a bit more work -- add a third parameter to `is_match` with the variable bindings you've seen so far, then write function clauses for them similar to the clause for `'_'`.

Granted, this won't be the fastest method.  With the caveat that I haven't actually measured, I expect using the pattern matching in the language using a fun will give much better performance, although it does make the call site a bit more verbose.  It's a trade-off you'll have to consider.

Answer (score 0):

May use [`ets:match`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#match-2):

```
6> ets:match(T, '$1'). % Matches every object in the table
[[{rufsen,dog,7}],[{brunte,horse,5}],[{ludde,dog,5}]]
7> ets:match(T, {'_',dog,'$1'}).
[[7],[5]]
8> ets:match(T, {'_',cow,'$1'}).
[]
```